# JS: the '??' operator

Tags: javascript

how can I apply the ?? operator in JS (can I do it anyway ?) I just want to assing the default value to `someVariable` if `defaultDirection` is undefined or get the `defaultDirection` value if it's not

```
function myFunc(defaultDirection) {
    var someVariable = defaultDirection ?? false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use pipes to do this:

```
function myFunc(defaultDirection) {
    var someVariable = defaultDirection || false;

}
```

Comment: Not exactly - this does not let you set `defaultDirection` to `0`.

Comment: good point! Never thought of that before actually